# Please assistance with MutationObserver script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mutation-observers

Please help to write this, I'm not good with javascript at all.

I have this kind of code:

```
<ul id="theul">
   <li id="firstli" style="display: something;"></li>
   <li id="secondli" style="display: something;"></li>
   <li id="thirdli" style="display: something;"></li>
</ul>
```

I want a script that will detect changes in the DOM about the "`display: something`" in all of this `<li>` tags.

If it's "`display: none`" => add "`someattribute="value"`" and delete "`anotherattrubute="anothervalue"`"

if it's "`display: block`" => add "`anotherattrubute="anothervalue"`" and delete "`someattribute="value"`"

I know only HTML and CSS unfortunately and never dealt with javascripting, can you please give me an example of how to do this so I will apply it for my site

I forgot to add this script I was found at here, but couldn't apply it because I don't know javascript.

```
window.MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
// Find the element that you want to "watch"
var target = document.querySelector("#demo");
// create an observer instance
observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutation) {
     /** this is the callback where you
         do what you need to do.
         The argument is an array of MutationRecords where the affected attribute is
         named "attributeName". There is a few other properties in a record
         but I'll let you work it out yourself.
      **/
mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        var list_values = [].slice.call(list.children)
            .map( function(node) { return node.innerHTML; })
            .filter( function(s) {
              if (s === '<br />') {
                return false;
              }
              else {
                return true;
              }
        });
        console.log(list_values);
      }
    });
});
// configuration of the observer:
config = {
    attributes: true // this is to watch for attribute changes.
};
// pass in the element you wanna watch as well as the options
observer.observe(target, config);
// later, you can stop observing
// observer.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* you are using jQuery at all, consider this plugin: https://github.com/eclecto/jQuery-onMutate

Using that plugin, the syntax would be something like this where *doSomething* is the callback function.

```
$('#theul > li').onModify('style', doSomething, true);
```